# FOSUserBundle Custom forms using Bootstrap

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle in my Symfony application. Everything work but i would like to know how to custom the render of the forms delivered by the bundle.
I have already succesfully custom the login form but i didn't find the way to custom for example the `changePassword.html.twig`.

I'have checked in `ChangePasswordFormType.php` to see if I can get the differents fields of the form but I must have missed something.

For example in my FOSUserBundle `login.html.twig`:

```
<form class="form-group-lg" action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
                            <fieldset>
                                {% if error %}
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ error|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</div>
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                        <input class="form-control" for="username" placeholder="{{ 'security.login.username'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">

                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                        <input class="form-control" for="password" placeholder="{{ 'security.login.password'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" />
                                    </div>
                                        <p class="text-right"> <a href={{ path('fos_user_resetting_request') }}> Mot de passe oublié ?</a></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" for="remember_me"/>{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" />
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
```

I'm looking for using the same syntax as `{{ 'security.login.username'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}` for the others template provided by `FOSUserBundle`to get boostrap theme on it.

If someone have already done that i would like to know how you've done this.
Thanks.

Comment: show some code ...  what exactly have you tried, what was the result ..

Comment: Usually overwriting the default template by creating a template with the same number in app/Resources/FosUserBundle/views/Resetting/reset.html.twig and app/Resources/FosUserBundle/views/Resetting/reset_content.html.twig works. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 3):

FOSUserBundle templates are located at : `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views/`
To override these templates, create the folder `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views` then, you create a template with the same name as the FOSUserBundle template you want to override.

For example to override the change passord template :
`vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views/ChangePassword/change_password.html.twig`
You must create `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/ChangePassword/change_passord.html.twig`